# Event Codes in linux Device Drivers (EVIOCG*)

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, keyboard-events

I have been working on driver code that uses event codes. But I haven't find any documentations regarding event codes in Linux drivers.

One thing I find out that mouse device driver uses this event codes for locating the mouse pointer. And another thing I know of event code is User space may get the current event code values using the EVIOCG* ioctls defined is linux/input.h

I am absolutely a fresher in device driver field.

I need help on under standing event codes in linux drivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the documentation of event codes and much more here

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/input?id=refs/tags/v4.1.3

Comment: Also [this link](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/input.h?id=refs/tags/v4.2-rc4#n100) can be helpful.